# Current NLP to SQL query solutions

Tags: sql, nlp

I need to create a system that converts natural language to SQL queries. I know this has been done before so I am trying to find an SDK, API, or company that has already done it instead of reinventing the wheel by trying to write it from scratch.

Most of the posts I find related to this topic are at least at couple of years old. Kueri.me seems to be a great solution but their downloads page isn't working and I can't find their SDK anywhere else online (their latest blog posts are also from 2016).

Any advice? What is currently the best solution to do NLP to SQL?

Comment: Take a look at nlp.abodit.com, it can do NLP to SQL including complex temporal expressions like "every Wednesday in May last year". [Disclaimer: I wrote it]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06868) tackles this problem and was recently nominated as best paper in a top conference.

They are gradually releasing and documenting code here: https://github.com/clic-lab/atis

**EDIT**

You could also use the OpenNMT library (https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py), to train a model to map natural language to SQL queries, if you have the training data.

Comment: Thank you, @jabalazs. Do you know of any companies that already provide this functionality?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any companies that provide that service. I updated my answer with another suggestion.